# SVM coordinate descent alpha

Tags: svm

In the dual formulation of SVM without slack, the final objective function is as follows which can be optimized via coordinate ascent.

[image]

My question is,

1. Do I evaluate the the value of the objective function at $\alpha = 0, 1$ then pick the max ?
2. Or do I compute the derivative wrt $\alpha$ and move towards the gradient ?

If the answer is not (1), then why ? Dont alpha only take 0 or 1 for the dual formulation without slack ?